# Why does Math.cbrt(1728) produce a more accurate result than Math.pow(1728, 1/3)?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

In JavaScript, `Math.cbrt(1728)` evaluate to the exact result of `12`.

However, the seemingly-equivalent expression `Math.pow(1728, 1/3)` evaluates to `11.999999999999998`.

Why do these results vary in precision?

Comment: Cool question - I didn't realize that `Math.cbrt()` performed like that.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate, but it does not seem to be a duplicate of the linked questions. 1.0/3.0 is not exactly representable as a floating-point number meaning the input to `pow()` has error. Exponentiation has the well-known property of magnifying error in the input (that is, the error in the output is larger than the error in the input). Assuming both `cbrt()` and `pow()` are implemented with similar maximum error (typically the case for high-quality math libraries) the computation `pow(x,1.0/3.0)` is thus less accurate than `cbrt(x)`. The latter will typically also be faster.

Comment: In fact, due to the issue I pointed out in my previous comments, a double-precision math library that correctly rounds both `cbrt()` and `pow()` will return exactly result stated in the question: `cbrt(1728) = 1.2000000000000000e+001  0x1.8000000000000p+3;
pow(1728,1.0/3.0) = 1.1999999999999998e+001  0x1.7ffffffffffffp+3`

Comment: I get `0x1.7ffffffffffff1172efp+3` for `pow(1728, 1.0/3.0)`, which rounds as njuffa described.  Neato.

Comment: @njuffa It seem as `Math.cbrt` similarly implemented to `Math.pow(x,1/3)` according to this source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cbrt#Polyfill. Maybe this is different between each browser?

Comment: `1/3` is an irrational number; hence the output of *any* calculation with this number will be irrational... I don't see how you can expect anything else?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker `an irrational number is any real number that cannot be expressed as a ratio of integers` neither of the numbers are irrational.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky Right; I stand corrected. I thought that any infinite number was *also* irrational; in any case, it is infinite.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker This is fraction; infinite number is hyperreal number. (Which can't really represent like this.)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky Yes, but that's not JS sees things? `1/3` evaluates to `0.33333...`, AFAIK there is no way to represent a fraction like this in JS without using external libraries.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes but according to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cbrt#Polyfill), `Math.cbrt` is similarly implemented to `Math.pow(x,1/3)`.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: that link only refers to how to add something similar to `Math.cbrt` if it is not available from the implementation. The native version uses a different function which should be more accurate that simply doing `Math.pow(x, 1/3)`.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy You are right, I am not web programmer; I didn't knew what polyfill is.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063755/computing-a-correctly-rounded-an-almost-correctly-rounded-floating-point-cubic

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A couple of general remarks up front:

1. As explained in this [seminal
   paper](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html),
   due to finite precision and range limits, floating-point arithmetic
   is sufficiently different from real mathematics (for example, lack
   of associativity) that mathematically equivalent expressions are not
   necessarily equivalent when evaluated in floating-point arithmetic.
2. Standards for computer languages do not typically guarantee any
   particular accuracy for math functions, or identical error bounds
   between different math functions such as `cbrt()` or `pow()`. But
   math libraries that deliver correctly rounded results for a given
   precision do exist, such as
   [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/).

In this case however, `cbrt(x)` will deliver more accurate results than `pow(x,1.0/3.0)` even when both functions are correctly rounded for all inputs.

The issue is that `1.0/3.0` cannot be represented exactly as a floating-point number, whether in binary or decimal. The IEEE-754 double precision number closest to one third is 3.3333333333333331e-1 (or 0x1.5555555555555p-2 when expressed in the C/C++ hexadecimal floating-point format). The relative representational error is -5.5511151231257827e-17 (-0x1.0000000000000p-54), meaning the best double-precision representation of 1/3 is somewhat smaller than the desired mathematical value.

This initial error in one of the inputs of `pow()` is not only passed through to the output, it is magnified due to the error magnification property of exponentiation. As a result, `pow(x,1.0/3.0)` will generally deliver results that are too small compared to the desired cube root, even if `pow()` delivers correctly rounded results. For the example in the question, the correctly rounded results are

```
cbrt(1728.0)        = 1.2000000000000000e+1  (0x1.8000000000000p+3)
pow(1728.0,1.0/3.0) = 1.1999999999999998e+1  (0x1.7ffffffffffffp+3)
```

that is, the result from `pow()` is one [ulp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) smaller than the result from `cbrt()`. For arguments large in magnitude, the difference will be much larger. For example, if `x` is 2<sup>1022</sup>, the respective results differ by 94 ulps:

```
x              = 4.4942328371557898e+307  (0x1.0000000000000p+1022)
cbrt(x)        = 3.5553731598732904e+102  (0x1.965fea53d6e3dp+340)
pow(x,1.0/3.0) = 3.5553731598732436e+102  (0x1.965fea53d6ddfp+340)
```

The relative error in the result of `pow()` in this example is 1.3108e-14, demonstrating the magnification of the relative error mentioned above.

For reasons of both accuracy and performance, math libraries that implement `cbrt()` therefore *typically* do not map `cbrt(x)` to `pow(x,1.0/3.0)` but use alternative computational schemes. While implementations will differ, a commonly used approach is to start with an initial low-precision approximation followed by one or several steps of [Halley's method](http://www.mathpath.org/Algor/cuberoot/algor.cube.root.halley.htm) which has cubic convergence.

As a rule of thumb, when a computer language offers both a dedicated cube root functionality and general exponentiation functionality, the former should be preferred to the latter for the computation of cube roots.

Comment: How did you write this within 5 minutes?! Do you have one of those brain-to-keyboard interfaces?

Comment: @lxg: I didn't. I have been applying minor corrections for the past five minutes. But it took me 20+ minutes to write.

Comment: Ah, my fault … I misinterpreted the "answered xx minutes ago". Need more coffee. Anyway, ~20 minutes is still impressive. ;)

Comment: @lxg: My professional background includes the design of microprocessor floating-point units and mathematical libraries, plus I already knew what I wanted to write when I requested to have the question re-opened.