# Safe computation of Geometric Mean

Tags: floating-point, average, precision, numerical-methods

I am looking for a reason to choose one of the following way to compute geometric mean of a long series of floating point `x`:

1. take nth root of each `x`, then multiply all of them
2. multiply all of them, then take nth root

I have heard that for floating point numbers, multiplications and divisions lose less information than additions and subtractions do. Therefore I am not considering the sum-exponent trick.

Should I compute geometric mean via 1 or 2, and why?

---

Update 1, in response to comment:

All x is less than 1 and in double precision. Their order of magnitude ranges between 10^-1 to 10^-6. Please assume the most common method for computing n-th root, since I am using a built-in function of a programming language. Instead of overflow, I am worried about underflow (?) since all values are less than 1. You can assume the length of the series of x to be in order of 10^8

Comment: How long is the sequence of floating-point numbers (order of magnitude)? How do you plan to compute the *n*-th root? For method (2), could there be danger of overflowing the floating-point format of your choice? Is performance any consideration?

Comment: Assuming there is no danger of overflowing double-precision floating point format and that accuracy is the most important design criterion, I would suggest using method (2), using a compensated product, then taking the *n*-th root at the end. For the compensated product (which can be computed very efficiently if FMA is available), see: Stef Graillat, "Accurate Floating-Point Product and Exponentiation", *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol. 58, No. 7, July 2009, pp. 994-1000. ([online copy](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~graillat/papers/IEEE-TC-prod.pdf))

Comment: Just a comment: in the exp-sum-log method, it's not really the additions and subtractions that are the main cause of accuracy loss (and in any case there are good algorithms for correctly rounded summation); it's the log calls. Not surprisingly, a function that maps the entire positive floating-point range into the interval (0.0, 710.0) introduces significant loss of information. @njuffa: Any chance of an answer encapsulating your comment?

Comment: Similarly, the nth root operation is going to lose significant information for large `n`; I agree with @njuffa that (2) is going to be significantly more accurate.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I don't want to write answer before the asker had a chance to clarify the items I inquired about.

Comment: @njuffa: Seems reasonable; I'd love to see the Graillat link in an answer at some point, though (I wasn't aware of that paper before). Oh, and while I'm here, (0.0, 710.0) should have said (-750.0, 710.0), of course (and I should have specified IEEE 754 binary64 format). It's too early in the morning.

Comment: The risk of overflow in method 2 can be avoided by accumulating the floating-point exponents separately.

Comment: @njuffa All `x` is less than 1 and in double precision. Their order of magnitude ranges between 10^-1 to 10^-6. Please assume the most common method for computing n-th root, since I am using a built-in function of a programming language. Instead of overflow, I am worried about underflow (?) since all values are less than 1. You can assume the length of the series of `x` to be in order of 10^8.

Comment: Is there a reference implementation of geometric mean somewhere, that is very accurate? I have no idea how to judge any of these approaches wrt accuracy, or even basic correctness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, in a sequence of floating-point operations that also involves contracting operations such as square root or cube root, it is advantageous from an accuracy perspective to perform the contracting operations last. For example, `sqrt(1.0/x)` is more accurate than `1.0/sqrt(x)`, `sqrt(a*b)` is more accurate than `sqrt(a)*sqrt(b)`, and `cbrt(a*b*c)` is more accurate than `cbrt(a)*cbrt(b)*cbrt(c)`.

As a consequence, unless there is a danger of overflowing or underflowing the chosen floating-point format, such as IEEE-754 `binary64` (e.g. `double` in C/C++), in intermediate computation, method [2] should be chosen. Additional aspect relevant to accuracy: if *n*-th root is computed by exponentiation, such as `pow()` in C/C++, additional error will be introduced with every computed root, as explained in case of cube root in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951407/why-does-math-cbrt1728-produce-a-more-accurate-result-than-math-pow1728-1-3/26958154#26958154). Finally, the computation of the *n*-th root will be slower than a multiplication, so doing only multiplies with a final root computation at the end will also be a superior approach performancewise.

Very accurate results can be achieved with method [2] by using a compensated product (akin to the compensated addition provided by [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)). See the following paper for details:

Stef Graillat, "Accurate Floating-Point Product and Exponentiation", *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol. 58, No. 7, July 2009, pp. 994-1000 ([online](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~graillat/papers/IEEE-TC-prod.pdf))

This compensated product can be computed particularly efficient on systems that provide the FMA (fused multiply-add) operation in hardware. This is the case for all the common modern processor architectures, both CPUs and GPUs. C/C++ provide convenient access to this via the standard math functions `fma()`, `fmaf()`.

**Update**: Asker clarified in comment that the risk of underflow is imminent since there are on the order of 10<sup>8</sup> factors in [10<sup>-6</sup>, 10<sup>-1</sup>]. One possible workaround mentioned by @Yves Daoust in a comment is to separate the factors into mantissa and exponent and accumulate them separately. Whether this is practical will depend on the floating-point environment. While C and C++ provide the standard function `frexp()` for performing this splitting, this function may not be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. The logarithm of the product over a_i is the same as the sum of the logarithms of multiple values of a_i.
2. The exponent of a logarithm of some value returns the original value.
3. The n^th root of an exponential function is given by the same exponential function, where the exponent is divided by n.

Putting this all together, the geometric mean of a_i is given by taking the sum of the logarithms of a_i, dividing by n, and taking the exponent.

In short, `geom_mean(A) = e^(sum(ln(a_i)) / n)`, or `e^mean(ln(a_i))`.