# How can I obtain from n a number which raised to the power of itself equals n?

Tags: c++, math, pow

I have an integer `n`, and I want to obtain a number which raised to the power of itself equals `n`. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: Your question contradicts itself. Suppose `x^x = n` and `y^n = n`. Which number do you want to find, given `n`? `x` or `y`?

Comment: There are *always* rounding errors when working with floating point numbers

Comment: `std::pow(n, 1/n)` will most likely return 1

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Of course, `n` should be cast to some floating-point type before all calculations.

Comment: As the answers below have pointed out, solving `x**x = n` is *not* the same as computing the n-th root of n. However, to answer the last part of you question: computing the n-th root via `pow` can easily suffer from large errors due to the error magnification property of exponentiation; I provided a worked example for cube root in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951407/why-does-math-cbrt1728-produce-a-more-accurate-result-than-math-pow1728-1-3/26958154#26958154)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You question states two things.

> I want to get the `n`th root of `n`

This means finding the solution to `x^n=n`. For this `std::pow(n, 1./n)` would be a good thing. Note that `1/n` will likely perform integer division if `n` is an integer, so you may well end up with `std::pow(n, 0)` which is `1`.

> I want to obtain a number which raised to the power of itself equals `n`

This is something completely different. You are trying to solve `x^x=n` for `x`. Taking the specific case of `n=2` and [asking Wolfram Alpha about it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%3D2), it returns

> `x = exp(W(log(2)))`

where `W` would be the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). As far as I know this is not part of the C++ standard, so you'll likely have to find a library (in source code or dynamically linked) to compute that function for you. GSL might serve. Generalizing to different values of `n` should be obvious, though.

Comment: Set `x=exp(u)`, then `log(n)=x*log(x)=u*exp(u)` which is the inverse of LambertW so that `u=W(log(n))` and `x=exp(W(log(n)))`. No need for Wolfram Alpha except for inspiration.

Comment: @LutzL: Sure, I meant it as inspiration, and I used it as such myself since I hadn't had dealings with this function before. But even if I did, I want to educate others on how to come up with such keywords by themselves.

Answer (score 5):

So we want to solve the equation `x^x = n`. This is a quite different thing from finding y = n-th root of n in equivalent to `y^n = n`.

The first thing to do when looking at powers is to consider logs now using natural logs, 
`x ln x = ln n`. This does not help us too much and it's not a standard function, so some form of convergence routine will be needed and we want to solve `f(x) = x ln x - ln n = 0`. This function is nicely monotonic increasing a little faster than just x so it should be easy to solve.

We can use use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). First find the derivative
`f'(x) = log x + 1`. Starting with a guess `x1` an updated guess will be `x2 = x1 - f(x1) / f'(x)`. If you do this a few times it should converge nicely. In my experiment to find `x` such that `x^x = 21` it took 
just under 6 itterations to converge.

In psudocode

```
x[0] = ln(n);
for(i=0; i<6;++i ) {
    fx = x[i] * ln( x[i] ) - ln(n); 
    df = ln( x[i] ) + 1;
    x[i+1] = x[i] - fx / df;
}
println(x[6], pow(x[6], x[6]))
```

Comment: As `u=log(x)` solves `u*exp(u)=c=log(n)`, this can be solved using the LambertW function and its approximations. Using the approximation for large arguments `u=log(c)-log(log(c))` gives the initial value `x[0]=c/log(c)=log(n)/log(log(n))` from which Newton converges in very few steps. (In general you are doing something wrong if the scalar Newton method needs more than 15 steps. Usually it should be 3-6 steps to the basin of quadratic convergence, and then 3-4 steps to exhaust the double precision.)

Comment: @LutzL Found my problem, it was not the starting point, I was using log base 10 rather than natural logs. This meant I got the derivative wrong. With natural logs I'm getting much faster convergence, 5 steps does it.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: use `std::pow`.

You want to find `1/n`th power of `n`. There's a standard function which finds `y`th power of `x`, called `std::pow`. It's always a good idea to use a standard function unless you have a strong reason to not.

So, it's better to rephrase this question to "do you have any reasons to **not** use `std::pow`?", and, since you're asking community, looks like you don't.