# C++11 math library has changed?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)

I used mingw and eclipse with c++98 on my laptop. But on my pc I have vs2012.

Now I have a small problem, the math library seems to be completely different.

in c++98 I had access to `round` and `M_PI` with `math.h`. But in vs2012 it isn't there anymore. I made a google search and found the following reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

But `round` is not in cmath and it is not in math.h either. Also I am unable to find `M_PI`

Is there another math library?

Comment: For `round()`, see the x-ref.  C99 has `round()` in both `<math.h>` and `<tgmath.h>`, but MSVC still implements the archaic C89 standard which did not have `round()`.  `M_PI` is a POSIX-ish extension.  It is not surprising to me that the function and macro are missing.

Comment: If you define `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` before including `<math.h>` (or `<cmath>`) then `M_PI` will be defined.  They are not defined by default because they are not part of the C or C++ language standards.  Visual C++ 2012 does not define the `round` function, which is not part of C90 or C++03 (it is part of C++11 by way of the C99 Standard Library, which Visual C++ does not yet implement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are new in C++11. MinGW had it before because of C compat, but VS2012 is not a C99 compiler. M_PI is probably the same story. IOW, you were relying on implementation-specific behaviour with MinGW, now it's Standard behaviour but VS hasn't upgraded quite yet.

Answer (score 3):

`round()` is indeed in `<cmath>`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

`M_PI` is not part of C or C++ standard, but something that's provided on POSIX-complient systems. MinGW tries to mimic a POSIX environment, so it provides this.

You can get a very good approximation with `double pi = 4 * std::atan(1);`.

Answer (score 2):

`round` *should* be in the `<cmath>` header (see § 26.8 of the C++11 Standard, Table 119), and if it is not, it is an implementation bug. However, the `M_PI` constant is **not** part of the C++11 Standard (see the same Table 119), although some implementations do provide it.

For instance, with GCC 4.7.2 and the implementation of libstdc++ that comes with it, this code compiles:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int x = std::round(M_PI);
}
```

Make sure you are using the `std::` namespace qualification for `round()`.