# How to convert the double to become integer

Tags: c++, c, math

It is hard to explain the question, i would like to convert a double number to integer without rounding the value after the decimal point.
For example

```
double a = 123.456
```

I want to convert become

```
int b = 123456
```

I want to know how many digit there is, and move it back after calculated to become `123.456`

PS:I just want pure mathematical method to solve this issue, without calculating the character of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [round() for float in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)

Comment: Sorry, I selected the wrong wrong duplicate.

Comment: What is your exact problem?
You just want to know how many digits are there in the number?
or You want to convert the double to int?

Comment: You know that the *actual* representation of 123.456 has more than 3 decimal places, right?

Comment: And let's not even *try* to handle 234.500...

Comment: because i want to use modulus to perform some calculation, so i need to convert everything to int.

Comment: @user1151874, If you had told us that from the beginning, there would be a very simple answer mentioning `std::fmod`. Look up what an XY problem is and try to steer away from them for exactly this reason.

Comment: Indeed, `fmod` is the solution to OP's problem. This mess with converting to integers is **not correct**.

Comment: You should probably show what you want for several other possible values, such as 3.141592653589793238 or 278919224109913770.0, or 0.0000000003451929334523; that's ignoring 1.00E±100 and values with larger exponents.  Or you should constrain your problem better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: OP was just looking for a way to use the `%` operator on floating point numbers and asked the wrong question. :-)

Comment: thanks i think fmod can solve my problem.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, there's no solution to your problem because the number 123.456 **does not exist** as a double. It's rounded to 123.4560000000000030695446184836328029632568359375, and this number obviously does not fit into any integer type after you remove the decimal point.

If you want 123.456 to be treated as the exact number 123.456, then the only remotely simple way to do this is to convert it to a string and remove the decimal point from the string. This can be achieved with something like

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.13f", 123.456);
```

Actually figuring out the number of places you want to print it to, however, is rather difficult. If you use too many, you'll end up picking up part of the exact value I showed above. If you use too few, then obviously you'll drop places you wanted to keep.

Comment: That's a definite +1 answer :)

Comment: @PHI Nope, it's mine!! Unless there's a downvote, your upvote did not take. You can tell if you've upvoted a question because the up arrow is highlighted. Writing +1 doesn't actually cast a vote.  ;-)

Comment: There is a downvote. :-p You can click on the number (currently 1) to see it split as up and down votes (currently +2/-1).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hahaha ..... I know that much sir ... the up ARROW is highlighted on my screen so this is definitely my vote, may be there is a downvote. This is actually turning out to be funny :)

Comment: Maybe the downvoter was somebody who noticed that I accidentally posted the value as 80-bit extended `long double` instead of the value as `double`... Anyway it's fixed now.

Comment: Need to add a thing ... downvoters here just are extremely anxious to hit DV button ... He could have suggested via a comment for the minor improvement.

Comment: I think it would be nice if SO doubled the rep penalty for downvoting, but waived the penalty entirely if you post a comment within 5 minutes of the downvote...

Comment: I don't think this is the only way and I don't think this is the simple way. *printf functions come with quite a lot of overhead and they lack type safety, they are the last resort when everything else fails. In this case, `modf` is much more elegant, in my opinion.

Comment: @Lundin: `modf` does not do what OP asked for. It turns out OP was actually just looking for `fmod`, but the question had an XY problem, so none of these answers are really relevant to the problem OP was trying to solve. However, `snprintf` is the only way to solve the problem as OP originally asked it without a few hundred lines of arcane math or further assumptions about the possible input values.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
double a = 123.456;
int i;
char str[20];
char str2[20];
sptrintf(str,"%d",a);
for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
if(!str[i] == '.')
{
sptrintf(str2,%c,str[i]);
}
}
int b = atoi(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the canonical way to do this would be

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double d = 123.456;
  double int_part;
  double fract_part;

  fract_part = modf(d, &int_part);

  int i = (int)int_part*1000 + (int)(fract_part*1000);

  printf("%d", i);
}
```

where the literal 1000 is a constant determining the number of desired decimals.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the text `"123.456"` you can simply remove the decimal point and convert the resulting text representation to an integer value. If you have already converted the text to a floating-point value (`double a = 123.456;`) then all bets are off: the floating-point value does not have a pre-set number of decimal digits, because it is represented as a binary fraction. It's sort of like 1/3 versus .3333 in ordinary usage: they do not have the same value, even though we usually pretend that .3333 means 1/3.

Answer (score -1):

Multiply each time original value with *10^i*, increasing each time *i* until *abs(value' - abs(value')) < epsilon* for a very small epsilon. *value'* should be computed from the original each time, e.g.

```
value' = value * pow(10, i)
if ( abs(value' - abs(value')) < epsilon ) then stop
```

Originally I suggested that you should simply multiply by ten, but as R.. suggested, each time the numerical error gets accumulated. As result you might get a result of e.g. 123.456999 for an epsilon = .0000001 instead of 123.456000 due to floating point math.

Please note that you might exceed int type boundaries this way and might want to handle infinity values as well.

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams noted this might lead to problems with scenarios where you want to convert 123.500 to 123500. You might solve it by adding a very small value first (and it should be smaller than epsilon). Adding such a value could lead to a numeric error though.

Comment: Multiplying by 10 is a lossy operation, and doing it many times will accumulate error. If you really want to use this approach, you should probably use the original value times `pow(10,n)` rather than repeatedly multiplying by 10. But either way, it will have rounding errors.

Comment: This seems plain wrong to me. abs(value' - abs(value')) < epsilon is always true for positive value, and always false for negative value, irrespective of i. It seems to me that it's not possible to answer this question without considering representability.