# How does Float round when converting it into integer

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer

If I have

```
(float)value = 10.50
```

and do

```
int new_value = (int)value
```

what rules will round number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a finite value of floating type is converted to an integer type, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is **truncated toward zero**).

So in the case of `-10.5`, it's converted to `-10`.

> #### C++11 4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]
>
> An rvalue of a floating point type can be converted to an rvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. [ Note: If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. —end note ]

Comment: Although it is in the quote you mention, I would explicitly [mention that this can overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/1708801) and recommend `round` or something similar instead.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is quite simple: the number simply gets truncated to its integral part, in this case, to `10`. The fractional part gets dropped entirely. The same applies to negative numbers: `-10.5` would be converted to `-10`.

Comment: I tried something, and found, that float -20.50 will be -21 in integer - I guess, it's not so simple as truncating... Or I, as usual, doing wrong :)

Comment: @therainycat Interesting. What platform are you on? That behaviour looks strange to me. I would expect to get `-20`.

Comment: I write on PAWN, and sometimes work with files, made by C++. There's no construction as (int) in PAWN, so someone made include, in which (inc) just replaced to floatround(value, floatround_floor). So, I had bad values for numbers below 0

Comment: @therainycat sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about or how that applies to your question.

Answer (score 1):

When converted to integers, the fractional part of the float is dropped, meaning the float 10.5 will be converted to the integer 10, and the float -10.5 will be converted to the integer -10.

Comment: Are you sure? What about -10.5?

Comment: It is rounded towards zero, whether the number is positive or negative, so -10.5 becomes -10.

Comment: You mean “fractional” (but you wrote “decimal”) about the part of the floating-point number that is dropped by truncation.