# Type casting a double to long in C++ returns an incorrect value?

Tags: c++

Sorry if my question is too basic. But can someone explain me reason of below behavior?

```
int main () {

        double a =1.16;
        cout<<(a*100);   //returning 116
        cout<<(long)(a*100); //returning 115
        return 0;
}
```

Why first cout is returning 116 but second returning 115?

Please explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting a floating point number into an integral type results in a truncation of the fractional part. Only the integral part is retained. So if you have `115.9999999` as a floating point number, it would be converted to 115 as an integer.

Now, `1.16 * 100` does not yield `116.0` in [IEEE754 floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), but rather, a number very slightly smaller than `116`, i.e a number with an integral part equal to `115` and a fractional part very close to `1`. So you are left with `115`.

Comment: But in above example i have 116 to be converted to int

Comment: @MayankJain 116 is being output as `double`

Comment: (1.16*100) is 116 in double. It's not an int.

Comment: Sorry guys but still not getting how converting 116.00000 to long would give me 115?

Comment: @MayankJain Because you don't have 116.00000. You have 115.9999999... . Surround your code with `if ((a*100) == 116.0) { cout << "Equal!"; } else { cout << "Not equal!"; }` and you'll see that it goes through the else part.

Comment: So what do you think would be most safe option to convert it to long??

Comment: Can you represent 1.16 in a double? No. The number stored inside "a" is actually 1.15999999999999992006394222699 (assuming IEEE754 double representation). Hence your result, since casting to an integral type truncates.

Comment: @MayankJain See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/485525/96780) - and [its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/485546/96780).

Comment: Just in passing: any **conversion** from a floating-point type to an integral type truncates, regardless of whether there is a **cast** in the source code. So `long x = a * 100;` would produce 115, just as the cast expression in the example does.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed, thanks. I edited mentions of casts, since they confuse the issue.

Comment: @Erbureth - at the risk of seeming hyper-technical, 116.0000 can be exactly represented in floating point. The problem is with 1.16, which cannot, and the result of multiplying that value by 100 is **not** 116.

Answer (score 3):

```
double a = 1.16;
```

Its binary representation is `1.0010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111`.

`a * 100` is represented as `1110011.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`,  which is actually `115.99999999999999`.

Casting to `long` **truncates** the decimal part, so the number will become binary represented by `1110011`, which in base 10 is 115.

If you need to understand clearly how *floating point arithmetic* works, I suggest you [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a floating point number, it's more of an approximation and not one hundred percent accurate. If it's 115.9-something when using the long cast, the decimal will be truncated.

This could differ between processors and between compilers as well.