# Setting an array's size to the value of a const derived from the division of another constant

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, constant-expression

I have these two supposed constants:

```
int const MATRIX_SIZE = 1000;

int const LONGEST_LR_LINK = (int)floor(MATRIX_SIZE/2);
```

I am attempting to declare an array:

```
int lrLinkArray [LONGEST_LR_LINK];
```

I get the error:

> error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

It would not be that much trouble to manually plug in whatever half MATRIX_SIZE is for LONGEST_LR_LINK, but I am curious as to what a solution to this would be.  Is it bad practice to do any kind of calculation for a const?

Comment: @chris please no, [rolling your own floor is hard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/1708801) and not advised.

Comment: You don't need `floor` when dividing two positive integers.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, Yeah that's a good point.

Comment: @chris too bad most of the highly scored answers there have broken solutions and not enough downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integer division in C++ automatically rounds down. So if you have the definition

```
int const LONGEST_LR_LINK = MATRIX_SIZE/2;
```

then `LONGEST_LR_LINK` will indeed be a constant expression, and

```
int lrLinkArray [LONGEST_LR_LINK];
```

should be fine. Besides, `floor(MATRIX_SIZE/2)` doesn't do what you think it does, anyway; you'd have to write `floor(MATRIX_SIZE/2.0)` in order to force non-integer division.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I had it in my head that integer division would return a float remainder.

Answer (score 3):

```
int const LONGEST_LR_LINK = MATRIX_SIZE/2;
```

Integer division already rounds down.

Answer (score 2):

Integer division should do what you want, we can see this from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), in section `5.6` *Multiplicative operators* it says:

> [...]For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient
>   with any fractional part discarded;<sup>81</sup>[...]

To understand why it does not you have to realized that even though you initialize `MATRIX_SIZE` with a literal which makes it a constant expression [std::floor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) is not a [constexpr function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and therefore `LONGEST_LR_LINK` is also not a constant expression and can not be used for array bounds which require an integral constant expression.

Also, as far I understand old style C casts are also not allowed in constant expressions either.