# Scale float to full range of unsigned int

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, type-conversion

I have a *double* in the range `(0,1)` which I want to scale to the full range of a 32-bit *unsigned int* `(0,0xFFFFFFFF)`.

How can I do this in C++? I am not concerned about the edge cases, so long as there isn't any nasty overflows where the result wraps around.

Thanks

Comment: By (0,1), do you mean that both 0 and 1 are excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can simply do this

```
unsigned int result = (unsigned int)std::floor( 
    std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() * yourDoubleInRange01 );
```

Comment: An overflow will happen if `yourDoubleInRange01` is bigger than `0.5`. Use a 32-bit unsigned int (`uint32_t`) for `result` and the conversion.

Comment: To round the result, .5 could be added to the product, unsigned int result = (unsigned int)std::floor(.5 + (std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() * yourDoubleInRange01) );

Answer (score 2):

Solution with C++11's `lround`:

```
uint32_t convert_to(double v) {
  return std::lround(v * std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());
}

double convert_from(uint32_t v) {
  return static_cast<double>(v) / std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
}
```

Without `lround` ([round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c)):

```
uint32_t convert_to(double v) {
  return std::floor(v * std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() + 0.5);
}
```

Comment: `double test = 0.82004366063971901;
unsigned __int32 result = std::lround(test * std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());`
result is zero. ??

Comment: @user593062: I don't see any problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc3a94aff87e477a