# shortest funtion c++ of rounding a float number

Tags: c++, rounding, short

Which is the shortest form of this function(without changing the name of this)?

```
int NearestInteger(float N) 
{
    return round(N);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of Google ?

Comment: I didn't find anything!

Comment: @Vasiu: do your requirements differ from the functionality in answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c?rq=1)?

Comment: @Tony D: only the return type is different.

Comment: Isn't it exactly the way you wrote it? Why do you think there's a shorter version? Why do you think you need one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::round](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) function if you have C++11.

Otherwise, you may need to use one of them depends on your requirement [std::floor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) or  [std::ceil](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have C++11, you can do this:

```
int NearestInteger(float N) {
    return int(floor(N + 0.5f));
}
```

However, it may work incorrectly for large floats. First of all, if your number does not fit *int*, any trash can be returned. Second, it may return wrong results for numbers larger than 2^24, because [not each integer is exactly representable in single precision float number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e).

Comment: Excepting *"The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
represented in the destination type."* per 4.9/1 `[conv.fpint]`.

Comment: @TonyD Yes, you are right. The caller has to worry about overflow.