# How to multiply floating point in ANSI C?

Tags: c, ansi-c

The following code:

```
    float numberForFactorial;
    float floatingPart = 1.400000;
    int integralPart = 1;

    numberForFactorial = ((floatingPart) - (float)integralPart) * 10;

    printf("%d", (int)numberForFactorial);
```

Returns 3 instead of 4. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Probably because `1.40000` gets stored internally as `1.399999` or something like that. `(int)3.99999` is `3`, as expected.

Comment: What do you get when you do `printf("%0.6f\n", floatingPart);`?

Comment: To expand on @MadPhysicist's comment, conversion from floating-point to integer truncates toward zero.

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: yes i already know that the rounding of the floating point is one of the most tricky parts. (even people had died) but there is nothing in ANSI C that i can do to get the integer with value 3?

Comment: Yes, add `0.5` to the computation (if the number is positive), or use `round` .

Comment: i added 0.00001 before i make this question and it worked! but i thought that this is just a 'hack' that came up through my mind....

Comment: @Mad Physicist: I tried your printf and returned: `4.000000`

Comment: That is because `printf` rounds the digit you don't see, in this case the 7th decimal place.

Comment: You are relying on `floatingPart` being represented exactly and writing code that will fail if the representation is even the tiniest bit less than precisely 1.4 -- don't do that.

Comment: @Nikitas. My answer has a link to ideone example. You are correct that `0.6f` does not print the desired result. I had to use `0.8f` or more to start seeing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `float` closest to `1.400000` is slightly less than `1.4`. You can verify that by doing

```
printf("%0.8hf\n", floatingPart);
```

The result from [ideone](https://ideone.com/5bJwNR) is `1.39999998`. This means that 10 times the first digit after the decimal point is `3`.

To avoid this issue, use rounding instead of truncation. One easy way to round is by adding half before truncation:

```
printf("%d", (int)(numberForFactorial + 0.5f));
```

will print `4` as you were expecting. You can also use `round`, `rint`, `lround`, or `modf` to get the same result: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html. Rounding is a complex topic, so choose the method whose constraints match your situation best.

Comment: @Nikitas. Feel free to select this answer if it explained what needed explaining.

Comment: And yeah, floats are a pain in the a**.

Comment: Of course i would do but i just wonder if "adding half before truncation"  - which works perfectly - is a well known, accepted technique. On the other hand cannot find any other solution that do the job.

Comment: well i stopped thinking and googled a while and yes. accepted. thanks

Comment: It is a very common technique: https://www.google.com/#q=rounding+by+adding+0.5. The key is that `0.5` has an exact binary representation. You can't mess up with it. Well, you can, but it would be much harder.

Comment: Rounding via `(int)(numberForFactorial + 0.5f)` fails for a number of cases.  Better to use `round()` or `rint()`.

Comment: @chux. Can you give an example?

Comment: Candidates include 1) Any `-odd.5`  2) Any value not near the  `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]` range  3) Values where `x + 0.5` forms an inexact sum but would form an exact sum had the floating point number  1 or 2 more bits of precision.  4) The value just smaller than 0.5  5) See [Harder than it looks: rounding float to nearest integer, part 1](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1)

Comment: [@Shafik Yaghmour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/2410359) has  a good SO post (even though it is C++) it relates to C.

Comment: @chux Fair enough. I included a nod to your comment in the answer. Since the question is not really about that, I think that should be enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122237/discussion-between-chux-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 2):

This is due to binary representation of floating-point values. More specifically, the `0.4` or `2/5` cannot be expressed with mantissa as sum of any combination like 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...

The literal `1.400000` is stored as something closer to `1.399999976158142` in its binary representation. The cast to `int` truncates non-integer part, giving three as the final result.

To be pedantic, the C standard does not require binary-based representation of floating-point data type, however IEEE 754 is de facto the standad one in today's computing.

Comment: Hm... yes i know about the 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 thing when i studied "Computer Systems A Programmer's Perspective" Third Edition, Chapter 2, page 110