# std::round is not a member of std on android

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, android-ndk

I am using `std::round` from C++ 11 on a Qt app built for android & iOS. But on android, I get the error that
`std::round is not a member of std` in spite of including the `cmath` header.

How can I make `std::round` work on android ? Is there an alternative to `std::round` ?

Following is my android environment:

```
ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM = android-23
NDK version          = r13b
ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION = 4.9
```

Comment: This is https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82, fyi.

Comment: @DanAlbert Is there an upcoming release of NDK where these issues will be resolved ?

Comment: As the bug says, it's scheduled for r15. In case tl;dr, it should be noted that this will never be fixed for gnustl, and will actually be "fixed" by making libc++ reliable enough that there will be no reason to use gnustl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a few functions from the `cmath` header are missing from the Android-NDK, see [here](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82) for more details.

It's very easy to implement your own `round` function however:

```
template<typename T>
T round(T v) {
  return int(v + 0.5);
}
```

Or check other suggestions/implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485525/round-for-float-in-c).

Comment: `int(v + 0.5);` fails for many cases.  OK for learner code, yet not production code.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make std::round work on android ?

(EDIT: updated instructions)

Switch to NDK r18 and remove the `ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION = 4.9` line since `gcc` is now completely removed from NDK, defaulting to `clang`.