# How to write my own version of `std::nearbyint`

Tags: android, c++11, gcc, c++14, qmake

**I want to write my own version of** `std::nearbyint` which **takes a float & returns the nearest int**. This is because, it doesn't build on android gcc with `ndk 14b`. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460288/stdround-is-not-a-member-of-std-on-android) suggested for `std::round`.

Is it feasible ? **any suggestions** ?

I am using qmake with android gcc & it seems ridiculously difficult to build this math function no matter whatever compiler flag I use. tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739081/android-ndk-complains-stdnearbyint-is-not-a-member-of-std) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support). But, the problem seems to be that some math functions are missing in android gcc as suggested in [ndk issues](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82)

Comment: Please don't repost (essentially) the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739081/android-ndk-complains-stdnearbyint-is-not-a-member-of-std)

Comment: this question is different than the one you mentioned. this question is to the point & straight - " how to implement my own `std::nearbyint` ? "

Comment: I think eventually you have to deal with binary representation of floating point types.