# Why typecasting a double to int seems to round it after 16th digit?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    std::cout << (int)0.9999999999999999 << std::endl; // 16 digits after decimal
    std::cout << (int)0.99999999999999999 << std::endl; // 17 digits after decimal
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
0
1
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Double, not float, btw.

Comment: see my answer to [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24348037/1708801)

Comment: Try writing out those values as doubles, i.e., without the cast. That should make it all clear.

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate representation of `0.99999999999999999` is `1.0`.<sup>1)</sup>
The most accurate representation of `0.9999999999999999` is `0.999999999999999888977697537484`.

1) In 64-bit double precision IEEE754 floating point representation.

Since there is no rounding but truncation, one gives `1` and the other gives `0` when converted to an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate floating point representation of the value 0.99999999999999999 (17 digits after the decimal) is exactly 1.0.

The most accurate floating point representation of the value 0.9999999999999999 (16 digits after the decimal) is less than 1.0.

The conversion to int truncates one to 0 and the other to 1.