# how would you optimize this vectorized sum of harmonics?

Tags: c++, optimization, vectorization, simd, sse2

I'm summing a bounch of harmonics together, with different phase/magnitude each, using vectorization (only SSE2 max as SIMD).

Here's my actual try:

```
float output = 0.0f;
simd::float_4 freqFundamentalNormalized = freq * (1.0f / sampleRate);
simd::float_4 harmonicIndex{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
simd::float_4 harmonicIncrement{4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f};

// harmonics
const int numHarmonicsV4 = numHarmonics / 4;
const int numHarmonicsRemainder = numHarmonics - (numHarmonicsV4 * 4);

// v4
for (int i = 0; i < numHarmonicsV4; i++) {
    // signal
    simd::float_4 sineOutput4 = simd::sin(mPhases4[i] * g2PIf) * mMagnitudes4[i];

    for (int v = 0; v < 4; v++) {
        output += sineOutput4[v];
    }

    // increments
    mPhases4[i] += harmonicIndex * freqFundamentalNormalized;
    mPhases4[i] -= simd::floor(mPhases4[i]);

    harmonicIndex += harmonicIncrement;
}

// remainder
if (numHarmonicsRemainder > 0) {
    // signal
    simd::float_4 sineOutput4 = simd::sin(mPhases4[numHarmonicsV4] * g2PIf) * mMagnitudes4[numHarmonicsV4];

    for (int v = 0; v < numHarmonicsRemainder; v++) {
        output += sineOutput4[v];
    }

    // increments
    mPhases4[numHarmonicsV4] += harmonicIndex * freqFundamentalNormalized;
    mPhases4[numHarmonicsV4] -= simd::floor(mPhases4[numHarmonicsV4]);
}
```

but:

1. I think I can optimize it more, maybe with some math tricks, or saving in some increments
2. I don't like to repeat the "same code" once for `V4`, once for `remainder` (if the num of harmonics are not % 4): is there a way to put a sort of "mask" to the last V4 placing (for example) magnitudes at 0? (so it do the same operation in the same block, but won't sum to the final output).

Comment: It's expensive to horizontal-sum into `output` *inside* the loop.  Instead, accumulate into a sum vector and hsum once at the end.  [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764)

Comment: Hi mister @PeterCordes (really hoped in your effort on this question :)) `hsum` with SSE2? how would you do this?

Comment: The calculation is dominated by `sin` calculation. There exists some tricks to calculate the sinus iteratively (sin(a+b) = ...), without calling the `sin` function. In this case, you have to pay attention to accumulation of rounding errors, and recalculate the exact sinus from time to time.

Comment: Also, `sin` is very expensive compared to the rest of your code, depending on the precision vs. performance tradeoff you choose (or your library chose).  (Although `floor` is non-trivial without SSE4.1; a general version that handles possibly large numbers can be expensive: [Calculating floor & ceil of vector2 double using pre-SSE4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61233195).  if you don't need to handle huge numbers, rolling your own floor with add / subtract of large constants can round, although IIRC that trick only directly gives you the current rounding mode (to nearest, not toward -Inf)

Comment: @markzzz: I already linked the canonical Q&A about SSE1/SSE2 horizontal sums in the comment you're replying to.  My answer there is how I'd do that part.  That's why I linked it.

Comment: @Damien what to you mean with sin(a-b)? sin(kx) + sin(zx) is not equal to sin (kx + zx) :O can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: If you have a constant phase increment dphi, then `sin((n+1)dphi) = sin(n dphi) cos(dphi) + cos(n dphi) sin(dphi)`.  Same for `cos(n+1)dphi`. You calculate `cos(dphi)` and `sin(dphi)` only once .... The iterative formula is still valid if you have a phase at the origin. I have use this trick billions of times for Doppler generation

Comment: Your code looks somewhat like a naïve implementation of the inner loop of a [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_sine_transform) (if you actually want to calculate `output` for different offsets). You don't show how you initialize `mPhases4` in your snippet -- please check how to post a [mre].

Comment: @Damien not sure i'm following your math. I can cache `cos(dphi)` and `sin(dphi)`, but I still need to calculate `sin(n dphi)` and `cos(n dphi)` right? why this should be convenient?

Comment: You can calculate them iteratively. Look at @MSalters answer. A complex multiplication is cheaper than a sinus calculation.

Comment: @Damien: i really don't get what you are suggesting here :) complex multiplication? in any case, I need to use `e^(-ki)` using Euler formula :O

Comment: `e^(-ki)`  is a complex number. I don't really understand your point. All needed operations can be expressed with complex numbers.  Not absolutely necessary. A cosmetic simplification, same operations

Comment: @Damien but i still need to calculate exp for each phase multiplier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c1c3a334e3e03b8 are you saying that calculate exp instead of sin is cheaper?

Comment: Again, look at Msalters answer. You don't need to directly call `exp(i*)`, but implement the iterative formula and use a simple complex multiplication for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222401/discussion-between-markzzz-and-damien).

Comment: @Damien: notice that (as said in the question) each harmonics got its own phase. Thus, i don't have a constant phase increment. I don't think i take your approch here (even if i learn somethings new ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second part of the question is the easiest. Any harmonic with magnitude 0 does not affect the sine output, so you just pad `mMagnitude` to a multiple of 4.

As Damien points out, `sin(x)` is expensive. But by Euler, `exp(x)=cos(x) + i sin(x)`, and `exp(x+dx)==exp(x)*exp(dx)`. Each step is just a complex multiplication.

Comment: second part: how would you pad it faster? mMagnitudes4 is a `std::array<simd::float_4, 32> mMagnitudes4`: let say I've 13 harmonics, should i iterate from 13 to 15 and set 0.0f? not sure its efficient :)

Comment: I mean: would you do somethings like this? `for (int i = 0; i < numHarmonicsRemainder; i++) { mMagnitudes4[numHarmonicsV4][i] = 0.0f; }`

Comment: @markzzz: You set `mMagnitude[13]` through `[15]` to 0.0f *once*, where you initialize the other mMagnitude members. You eliminate the remainder part from the code shown, which is performance-critical. This means all math is now in the v4 part. Better for cache, better for branch prediction.

Comment: about your last statement, not sure if I follow the math. Any link/resource about summing harmonics?

Comment: @markzzz: It's not about "summing harmonics". It's a basic property of addition. `a+b+c+0` is just `a+b+c`. But `a+b+c+0` has 4 terms so it can be handled by your " v4" code.

Comment: I meant the Euler formula as "lasts statement" :)

Comment: @markzzz: You correctly noted that "sin(kx) + sin(zx) is not equal to sin (kx + zx)". Damien did have the correct formula for `sin (kx + zx)`, although he used different symbols. I tend to not remember all the sin/cos rules, but use Euler's formula to derive them. E.g. to work out the example `exp(x)*exp(dx)==(cos(x)+i sin(x)) * (cos(dx)+i sin(dx))` = `cos(x)cos(dx)-sin(x)sin(dx) + i sin(x)cos(dx) + i cos(x) sin(dx)` which gets you back to Damien's formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222398/discussion-between-markzzz-and-msalters).

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, make sure your implementation of `simd::sin` is fast. See `XMVectorSin` and especially `XMVectorSinEst` [in DirectXMath library](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/master/Inc/DirectXMathVector.inl) for an example how to make a fast one, or copy-paste from there, or include the library, it’s header-only. The instruction set is switchable with preprocessor macros, for optimal performance it needs SSE 4.1 and FMA3, but will work OK with SSE2-only.

As said in comments, you should only do horizontal add once, after all iterations of the loop are complete. Until then, accumulate in a SIMD vector.

Very minor and might be optimized by the compiler, but still, you should not access `mPhases4` like you’re doing. Load the value into vector at the start of the loop body, compute output, increment, compute fractional part, and store the updated value just once per iteration.

Comment: yes, the simd:sin is very nice and fast ;) (i.e. sse_mathfun_sin_ps, nice for dsp). about last part, do you mean `simd::float_4 phases4 = mPhases4[i];`, use phases4, than `mPhases4[i] = phases4;`? well of course, but I think compiler already does this for me. but i'll write this way ;)

Comment: @markzzz “sse_mathfun_sin_ps” Did a quick benchmark, `XMVectorSin` is 16% faster with SSE2, 50% faster with SSE4 and 109% faster with FMA3. `XMVectorSinEst` is even faster than that. “about last part” Yep, that’s exactly what I mean. “I think compiler already does this for me” usually but not always, C++ defines a memory model, compilers are only allowed to do that when they are certain no other thread is going to see that memory.

Comment: @markzzz By the way, you gonna try very hard to find an x86 device in working condition that doesn’t support SSE3 or 4.1. SSE3 arrived in later revisions of Pentium 4, SSE 4.1 was introduced in Core Solo/Duo, both ere supported universally since then, including AMD CPUs and Intel Atoms.

Comment: That's are the specific from the environment where i'm working in... can't decide myself :) anyway, not all x64 processors support SSE4. I build with -march=nocona, probably SSE3 are supported though...

Comment: @markzzz: Even though Nocona dates back to 2004, it indeed has SSE3. But do you really need to support 16 year old CPU's?

Comment: @markzzz SSE3 probably not gonna change anything, the jump from 16% to 50% is caused by roundps https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundps sin needs that to normalize the angle into [ -pi .. +pi ]. The SSE1 workaround takes 9 instructions and up to 4 memory references: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/aug2020/Inc/DirectXMathVector.inl#L2331-L2340